# Android Studio gradle update error

Tags: android

I am working on geofencing app in Android. If I set the

```
  dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'     
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.0.1'
    }
```

it works fine.If I changed it to

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'  
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.2'
}
```

I get following error.

**package com.google.android.gms.maps does not exist

package com.google.android.gms.maps.model does not exist**

Why? I need to set it to 11.0.2 for integrating it with other app.

Answer (score 0):

**Sync Project With Gradle File** may help. Just click the button next to AVD Manager or navigate through **Tools->Android->Sync Project With Gradle File**.

Answer (score 0):

Try to **sync your project with gradle** file but if **gradle sync failed** then download the latest version of gradle and specify its path under **build.gradle** and try to sync again.

Answer (score 0):

you got to install the **missing** google play services. 
Go to settings and update your google play services and google repository to latest version which is **46** means you got to use this version **11.0.46**

[image]